# SWIG: %ignore keeps giving "Syntax error in input(1)"

Tags: python, c++, swig

Forgive me if this question is silly, but I can't find a good example of %ignore being used around the web. I'm trying to generate a python wrapper for C++ code using the following command:

```
swig -python -c++ sample.i
```

I have an interface file like the following:

```
%module sample
%{
#include <file1.h>
#include <file2.h>
%}

%ignore vprint
%include <file1.h>
%include <file2.h>
%include <file3.h>
```

I'm trying to exclude the vprint function, defined in file1.h, because it takes in a va_list as a parameter, which SWIG doesn't support the wrapping of. When I include the %ignore statement, I get an error stating "Syntax error in input(1)". Without it, I get the normal error telling me I can't wrap the function I'm trying to ignore. Why might this error be occurring? Thanks in advance!

Comment: It is probably something in your headers, e.g. a `__declspec(dllexport)`, which you can make SWIG accept by including `windows.i` or something different. Remember that SWIG cannot recurse headers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You certainly need a semicolon after the `%ignore`:

```
%ignore vprint;
```

Comment: Thank you! I got a bit confused because none of the other SWIG files I've written so far have needed semicolons.

Comment: @GenericAlias SWIG can be a little inconsistent with semicolon requirements. Usually extra ones don't do any harm though.